# Is this type assertion ever valid?

Tags: go

I am reading the source code for Go's io package and I came across a snippet I don't fully understand. Here it is

```
func WriteString(w Writer, s string) (n int, err error) {
    if sw, ok := w.(stringWriter); ok {
        return sw.WriteString(s)
    }
    return w.Write([]byte(s))
}
```

where

```
type stringWriter interface {
    WriteString(s string) (n int, err error)
}

type Writer interface {
    Write(p []byte) (n int, err error)
}
```

The type assertion `w.(stringWriter)` asserts that the dynamic type of w (i.e. Writer) implements the stringWriter interface. I don't see how this is possible given the type definitions of stringWriter and Writer. Assuming that this code is correct, what is it that I am missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily build a type which implements `Writer` as well as `stringWriter`:

```
type StringWriter struct{}

func (s StringWriter) Write(in []byte) (int, error) { 
    return 0, nil 
}
func (s StringWriter) WriteString(s string) (int, error) { 
    return s.Write([]byte(s)) 
}
```

So passing an instance of `StringWriter` to `io.WriteString` results in `StringWriter.WriteString`
being called.

The logic behind `io.WriteString` is: Use `WriteString` on the writer if it has such a method 
or fall back to `string` to `[]byte` conversion otherwise. To test whether the instance implements
a method or not, interfaces are used, as these are just method sets and can be tested for easily.

Comment: So obvious it's almost embarasing. Too much time in front of the keyword made me forget that `func WriteString(w Writer)` will accept anything implementing the Writer interface. Thank you.